# Yesterday date at the start of new mounth(Python)

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am just learning to program and I apologize for such a stupid question.

I need to find yesterday date, i use for it

```
import datetime


yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print(yesterday)
```

Output:

```
2021-09-18
```

And I asked myself this question:

Will it `yesterday` equal to `"2021-08-31"` if `datetime.date.today()` == `"2021-09-01"`

Or `yesterday` will be equal to `"2021-09-00"`

Comment: This is something you could very easily test yourself. `datetime.datetime(year=2021, month=9, day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)`

Comment: Oh thanks, I checked, this is the last day of last month,nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'll be equal to 2021-08-31.